# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers, char

**My code is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i = 0;
    int count = argc - 1;
    char *numbers = malloc(count * sizeof(char));
    for(i = 1 ; i <= argc ; i++){
       printf("%s ", argv[i]);
       numbers[i] = argv[i];
    }
    printf ("%s \n", numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

**The error that came is:**

> tamal@baba-desktop:~/Desktop/c$ cc experiment.c -o experiment
>
> experiment.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> experiment.c:10:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer
>   without a cast [enabled by default]

**I tried**   `numbers[i] = &(argv[i]);` **at line 10. Still the same result.**

Comment: What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: `char *numbers = malloc(count * sizeof(char) + 1); int j = 0;
    for(i = 1 ; i <= count; i++){
       printf("%s ", argv[i]);
       numbers[j++] = *argv[i];
    } numbers[j] = 0;`

Comment: I wanted to print the values passed to argv one at a time. Then print at one go the items together.

Comment: You mean you are trying to concatenate strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to dereference argv twice to get the char value `numbers[i] = *(*(argv + i));`

Comment: Now the output is 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

Comment: Oh you've indexed beyond the end of argv, should change to i < argc.

Comment: Is there any problem with line 12 'printf ("%s \n", numbers);'  because nothing is printed.

Comment: You're trying to print just a regular array of char as a string. You should allocate count + 1 for numbers then after the for loop set number[i] = '\0' so the char array becomes a null  byte terminated char array i.e a C string.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `numbers[i]` is of type `char`, whereas, `argv[i]` is of type `char *` and both are not the same. That's why the warning is there.

In the second case, `numbers[i] = &(argv[i]);` is also wrong, as `&(argv[i]);` is also not a `char`.

The bottom line is, you have a `char` pointer `numbers` and when you use indexing operator on it, you get the inidiviual elements as `char`, i.e., all the `numbers[i]` are of type `char`. You need to assign another `char` value to it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done as if there are more than 2 arguments:

```
int count = argc - 1;
char **numbers = (char **)malloc(count * sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++){
   printf("%s ", argv[i + 1]);
   // Stores all arguments except "experiment"(i.e. exe file).
   numbers[i] = argv[i + 1];
}
for(i = 0; i <= count; i++){
   printf("%s\n", numbers[i]);
}
```

And if there is only two arguments then it should be done simply as:

```
char *number = (char *)malloc(1*sizeof(char));
// Store argument other than provided .exe file i.e. "experiment"
number = argv[1];
printf("%s\n", number);
```